# SIM ToolKit menu access with AT commands using c# using huawei

Tags: c#, at-command, sim-toolkit

i am trying to develop a sim toolkit access software using c#

```
AT^STSF=1

returns ok
```

then

```
AT^STGI=0,0
```

it returns

```
^STGI:0,2,"566F6461666F6E65205365727669636573"
^STGI:128,2,"5072657061696420526566696C6C",0,33
^STGI:129,2,"4C616E6775616765",0,33

OK
```

i am expecting a menu selection string but it come like this

Comment: the values are hex values. Convert them to text using any hex converter.

Comment: 566F6461666F6E65205365727669636573 = Vodafone Services
5072657061696420526566696C6C = Prepaid Refill
4C616E6775616765 = Language

converted from: [link](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.htm)